# Evernote Cloud SDK 2.0 for PHP and Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, evernote

I am trying to integrate the `evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php` package on a Laravel v`5.1.30` app.

I tried installing it via composer with `composer require evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php dev-master` and with `composer require evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php` but had no success. Even though I've set the `"minimum-stability": "dev"` in my composer.json I am still getting

> Problem 1
>    - Installation request for evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php dev-master -> satisfiable by evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php[dev-master].
>    - evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php dev-master requires ezyang/htmlpurifier ~4.6.0 -> no matching package found.

In my composer.json file I already have a `"ezyang/htmlpurifier": "^4.7"` entry. It seems to be a dependency for laravel.

> $> composer depends ezyang/htmlpurifier
>   laravel/laravel  dev-integrate_evernote  requires  ezyang/htmlpurifier (^4.7)

Any ideas on how I could do this integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a small modification. Would you mind testing it before I push to the main Evernote repo ?

Please add this to your composer.json file :

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type":"vcs",
        "url":"https://github.com/Laurent-Sarrazin/evernote-cloud-sdk-php.git"
    }
],
"require":{
     "evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php":"dev-master"
}
```

And run

```
composer update evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php
```

Instead of fetching from the evernote repo it should fetch the sdk from my repo where I've just made the change.
Let me know if this work. I'll then push to the Evernote repo and you'll be able to go back to the "normal" install process.

And BTW, I've been unable to reproduce (Tried with a clean install of laravel 5.1.33). Seems that something else in your app requires HtmlPurifier.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks, I really appreciate it! P.S. You are right about the htmlpurifier it is needed for something else, I got digging a bit to found where it is used and it is not the framework using it.

Comment: Great. I've just pushed to the Evernote repo. You can (and should) remove my repository from your composer.json file.